# SharePoint 2010: Tag profile not showing all tagged items

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tags

After tagging some items, I go to the tag profile and can´t see the items that were tagged, neither choosing “all” or “popular in the last 60 days”.

These are the things I verified:

1) I’m making sure these two jobs run every minute,

User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance Job   Minutes
User Profile Service Application - Social Rating Synchronization Job

2) Tried full and incremental crawls, same result.

3) Don’t have any columns chosen in the “searchable columns” excluded columns list.

Any idea? Other job that collects this info, something I’m missing?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: After a day, I see the items being tagged. Which means, there are some services, along with full crawling, that are causing this info to appear. Which are those services/jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. Two conditions must be met:

1. Search service account must have "Retrieve people data for search crawlers" permission
2. Job “User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance Job” must be run.